# Background-color disappears (intermittently) in Chrome on my contact page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

On my contact page, and only in Chrome (this resolves fine in Firefox, Edge, and on my TA's Safari Browser, the background disappears most of the time. For my TA's Macbook, when she hovers over a box, the issue resolves itself. My version of Chrome is 63.0.3239.132.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="h-100p" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Daniel G Richmond</title>
        <link href="./assets/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="./assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body class="bgc-388E3C d-f fd-c h-100p pad-20px">
        <section class="fl-1">
        <header>
            <nav class="ai-b bb-s c-E8F5E9 d-f jc-sa">
                <p class="fs-300p w-61p">Daniel Richmond</p> 
                <div class="ai-b d-f jc-sa w-39p">
                    <a class="bdc-FFEB3B bds-s bgc-1B5E20 bw-3 c-E8F5E9 d-b fs-200p pad-20px ta-c td-n bgc-1B5E20-hv" href="./index.html">About</a>
                    <a class="bdc-FFEB3B bds-s bgc-1B5E20 bw-3 c-E8F5E9 d-b fs-200p pad-20px ta-c td-n bgc-1B5E20-hv" href="./portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                    <a class="bdc-FFEB3B bds-s bgc-1B5E20 bw-3 c-E8F5E9 d-b fs-200p pad-20px ta-c td-n bgc-1B5E20-hv" href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="content" class="ai-fs d-f jc-sa mt-5p">
            <form action="/tbd" method="POST" id="contact" class="bdc-FFEB3B bds-s bgc-1B5E20 bw-3 w-55p">
                <div><h2 class="bb-s c-E8F5E9 fs-200p">Contact Me</h2></div>
                <div class="c-E8F5E9 fs-150p pad-1p"><label for="firstName">First Name:</label></div>
                <div><input class="ml-5p w-30p" type="text" id="firstName" name="first_name"></div>
                <div class="c-E8F5E9 fs-150p pad-1p"><label for="lastName">Last Name:</label></div>
                <div><input class="ml-5p w-30p" type="text" id="lastName" name="last_name"></div>
                <div class="c-E8F5E9 fs-150p pad-1p"><label for="mail">E-mail:</label></div>
                <div><input class="ml-5p w-30p" type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail"></div>
                <div class="c-E8F5E9 fs-150p pad-1p"><label for="msg">Message:</label></div>
                <div><textarea class="ml-5p w-30p" id="msg" name="user_message">Type your message here!</textarea></div>
                <!-- There will eventually be JavaScript and MySQL to make the button do what I want it to do! -->
                <div  class="c-E8F5E9 fs-150p pad-1p"><button type="submit">Send your message</button></div>
            </form>
            <aside class="bdc-FFEB3B bds-s bw-3 bgc-1B5E20 w-30p">
                <h2 class="bb-s c-E8F5E9 fs-200p pad-20px">Connect with me!</h2>
                <div id="connections" class="d-f fb-30p fg-1 jc-sa mt-5p">
                    <a href="https://github.com/Sonic12040"><img class="pad-5p" src="./assets/images/gitHub.png" alt="GitHub"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/danielgrichmond"><img class="pad-5p" src="./assets/images/linkedIn.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
                    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/9054375/daniel-richmond"><img class="pad-5p" src="./assets/images/stackOverflow.png" alt="Stack Overflow"></a>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </section>
        </section>

        <footer class="bt-s c-E8F5E9 fs-0 pad-20px">
            <p class="fs-200p ta-c">Copyright &copy;2018 by <a href="mailto:daniel.g.richmond@gmail.com">Daniel G Richmond</a></p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS File (I also have a reset.css):

```
.bb-s {
border-bottom: solid;
}
.bdc-FFEB3B {
    border-color: #FFEB3B;
}

.bds-s {
    border-style: solid;
}

.bgc-1B5E20 {
    background-color: #1B5E20;
}

.bgc-1B5E20-hv:hover {
    background-color: #00C853;
}

.bgc-388E3C {
    background-color: #388E3C;
}

.bt-s {
    border-top: solid;
}

.bw-3 {
    border-width: 3px;
}

.c-E8F5E9 {
    color: #E8F5E9;
}

.d-b {
    display: block;
}

.d-f {
    display: flex;
}

.f-l {
    float: left;
}

.fb-30p {
    flex-basis: 30%;
}

.fd-c {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.fg-1 {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.fs-0 {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.fl-1 {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.fs-150p {
    font-size: 150%;
}

.fs-200p {
    font-size: 200%;
}

.fs-300p {
    font-size: 300%;
  }

.h-100p {
    height: 100%;
}

.h-128px {
    height: 128px;
}

.jc-sa {
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.ml-5p {
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.mt-5p {
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.pad-1p {
    padding: 1%;
}

.pad-5p {
    padding: 5%;
}

.pad-20px {
    padding: 20px;
}

.ta-c {
    text-align: center;
}

.td-n {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.w-28p {
    width: 28%;
}

.w-30p {
    width: 30%;
}

.w-39p {
    width: 39%;
}

.w-40p {
    width: 40%;
}

.w-55p {
    width: 55%;
}

.w-61p {
    width: 61%
}

.w-128px {
    width: 128px;
}
```

Comment: I haven't used Chrome in a while, but I remember there being a bug related to this. Not sure if it was ever resolved.

Comment: Yeah, updating Chrome lessened the issue. It now shows the background again when I hover over the nav, but that's unfortunate, because Chrome has a huge browser share, and I'd like my first class project not to bomb.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xeno1100/e7te2epn/2/

You will see that your backgrounds are working in Chrome. Most likely your problem is in your reset.css.

Here's an example with Eric Meyer's reset 2.0 that does work in Chrome:
https://jsfiddle.net/xeno1100/e7te2epn/5/

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Here's a direct link to the reset.css
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

Comment: That is the exact version of reset.css I'm currently using (with a commented credit to meyerweb).